# Hibernate model data not saved in database

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 5 tables data those needs to be saved at a same time into database.My code snippet is as below.

```
public boolean addStudentDetail(RegisterLoginDetail registerLoginDetail,
            StudentRegisterBasicDetail studentRegisterBasicDetail, StudentBoardDetail studentBoardDetail,
            StudentSchoolDetail studentSchoolDetail, StudentAdditionalDetail studentAdditionalDetail,
            StepCompletionMatrix stepCompletionMatrix) {
        boolean isSuceess = true;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(registerLoginDetail);
            session.saveOrUpdate(studentRegisterBasicDetail);
            session.saveOrUpdate(studentBoardDetail);
            session.saveOrUpdate(studentSchoolDetail);
            session.saveOrUpdate(studentAdditionalDetail);
            session.saveOrUpdate(stepCompletionMatrix);
            transaction.commit();
            
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            isSuceess = false;
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return isSuceess;
    }
```

But for my two transaction data entry for insert operation not found in StudentRegisterBasicDetail table and all other table contains entry for one common id shared between each table.My webapplication is in pilot testing mode and concurrent users are making entry through form.So I am not able to figure out  for which reason my entry being skipped in that table.There is no exception log for that table entry and if exception occurs then rollback for all table should be happen or not?

Please help me...

Comment: How many times did you call `addStudentDetail` in your test run and how many `studentRegisterBasicDetail` records are missing? A

Comment: Total 35 different users separately calls this method at different time in concurrent environment and out of which 2 user entry was missing in that table

Comment: And the primary key for studentRegisterBasicDetail is user assigned or database generated?

Comment: primary key is database generated

Comment: I thought there could be contention in the service if you are generating the primary key. But if it is database generated, that is out of the question. You were talking about some common id across all tables, what is it? where is it generated?

Comment: commen id is of RegisterLoginDetail  table and its primary key which will be mapped with all other tables and first entry is already made in RegisterLoginDetail table at the time of fresh registration

Comment: If it is reproducible on every test run,  I would collect all the ids of each entity saved in `addStudentDetail` method and concat it as one `System.out.println` just before transaction commit ( `session.saveOrUpdate` should return the object with the generated primary key).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218049/discussion-between-jay-shah-and-kavithakaran-kanapathippillai).